# jsoup connection HTTP error 406

Tags: java, multithreading, http, connection, jsoup

I have a Java program that has been running with no issues until last week.  I am now getting the HTTP error 406 when trying to connect to web pages.  Below is the code:

```
            Document doc1;              
            doc1 = Jsoup.connect(sChartLink).timeout(iTimeOut).get();
```

The iTimeout is set to 15000.
An example of the sChartLink is https://www.investing.com/equities/allianz-ag

I am using threads as well for this program so that I can run multiple processes within a given time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Eddi Rae

Answer (score 0):

The 406 Not Acceptable is an HTTP response status code indicating that the client has requested a response using Accept- headers that the server is unable to fulfill. This is typically a result of the user agent (i.e. browser) specifying an acceptable character set (via Accept-Charset), language (via Accept-Language), and so forth that should be responded with, and the server being unable to provide such a response.
So you should change your request header and try again.

Comment: So how would I change the statement above?

Comment: I have added a UserAgent field to the connection for JSoup, but I am still getting this error...   String ua = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)";
    doc2 = Jsoup.connect(sPPChartLink).timeout(0).userAgent(ua).get();  Can you give me any advice on what else to try, please?

Comment: 1. Try to get the network package, e.g. install WIRESHARK to get the sending/receiving data, then compare the package to the normal one. 2, you may contract the service provider for help

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your code is the problem here.
I believe Investing.com will pick up the fact that you are trying to mine their data, and start returning HTTP 406.